# Chrome Extension login whtih own database

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create a Login for my Chrome Extension. So that you have to login by the Popup.hmtl from the extension to reach access to the functions of the extension using a own Database or with users I can create

Comment: Why not? Do it.

Comment: @wOxxOm how will i do this

Comment: By doing it, I suppose. Your question is too broad so it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see...

If you have a server that will store usernames and passwords, yes you could do it. You can write an extension that validates user login against that remote server.

But you don't mention that.

If you wanted a single user to be able to use the extension maybe because other people use the computer, you could let the user set up a password in local storage so that only they could use the extension. Note it wouldn't be very secure - a programmer could easily access the password but it would deter most people.

You could build the extension with built in usernames and passwords. Again, this would be insecure against a programmer.

As @wOxxOm says your question is too broad.